# Perform Segue From Another Swift File via a class function

Tags: ios, swift

How can I use a class function I implement to perform a segue if the class it is held in is not connected to a viewController?

Comment: If it's a class-level function, it's available wherever you import the class without needing to create an instance. In your `IBOutlet`, call `YourClass.function()`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I have that functioning. I want the called function to perform a segue. Is that possible?

Comment: A class function, by definition, is not associated with a specific instance of the class, and hence has no access to instance methods such as `performSegue...` or instance properties such as `storyboard`  I'd suggest reconsidering why you have a class function and not an instance function.  Although it sounds like you really have an instance function as used in Antonio's answer.

Comment: @David I chose to use a class function to keep from having large amounts of unnecessary code in my viewControllers. Code that will need to be ran multiple time from different views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to perform a segue, you need the instance of view controller where the segue originates from - for example:

```
class MyViewController {
}

class MyClass {
    showNextView(fromViewController: UIViewController) {
        fromViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_id", sender: fromViewController)
    }
}
```

However I discourage this kind of interaction. Don't tell the view controller how to show a view - let it do on its own, and just ask it.

So, I suggest creating an instance method in your view controller:

```
class MyViewController {
    ...
    func goToNextView() {
       performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_id", sender: self)
    }
}
```

and use that to make the transition:

```
class MyClass {
    showNextView(fromViewController: MyViewController) {
        fromViewController.goToNextView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a HomViewController with moveToScreen() function, like this:          func moveToScreen(){ self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ListReport", sender: self) } . And I set "ListReport" Identifier. Now when I create a file with: class Build { let home = HomViewController()          home.moveToScreen() } is crash with error: has no segue with identifier 'ListReport' . Why it is crash?

Comment: @Antonio `fromViewController.goToNextView()` in MyClass is never called. I put print statements inside the curly braces and nothing is print out.

Comment: @Antonio , I have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458405 , I'd appreciate if you could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct the currently visible view controller to segue using "performSegueWithIdentifier".

You obviously need a reference to the visible controller.

Inside your method use:

```
currentViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: currentViewController)
```

Comment: I am calling a class function not in a viewController. How can I perform the segue by just calling my function. For instance.
    licenseAgent.checkLicense() 

within that function I want to check the license and if it isn't present, I wish to log the use out.

Comment: You would have to inject a reference of the current view controller to that function/class and call its "performSegueWithIdentifier" method