# UIView is not hidden when condition is met in if else statement

Tags: swift, uiview

I am trying to create an animation and hide it 5 seconds after the task has been completed.
For some reason `overlayView` is not hidden off the screen when `counter == 5`.

```
 var counter = 0
 var timer = Timer()
 let paymentLogo = UIImage(named: "paymentImage")
 var imageLogo:UIImageView!
 var overlayView = UIView()
 var logoAppeared:Bool? = false
 let labelLogo = UILabel()


  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     //move picture off screen
     animateDidLayout()
  }


  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   //move picture on screen and adjust view
     animateDidAppear()
 }

//called by timer every 1 seconds
  func startCounting() {
     if counter == 5 {
        self.timer.invalidate()
         self.overlayView.isHidden = true //it is not hidden
          self.imageLogo.isHidden = true
           self.labelLogo.isHidden = true
             self.logoAppeared = true
                 print("counter in if \(counter)")
         } else {
           counter += 1
            print("counter in else \(counter)")
     }
 }


    //animate the image before it appears on screen
       func animateDidLayout(){
          guard let appeared = self.logoAppeared, appeared == false else{
            print("appeared is true in viewDidLayoutSubviews, in else")
             return
     }

     print("appeared value after else in ViewDidLayoutSubvies \(appeared)")

     //animate overlayView
     self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
      self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
       self.overlayView.alpha = 0.4
        self.view.addSubview(self.overlayView)


   //animate imageLogo
     self.imageLogo = UIImageView(image:paymentLogo)
      imageLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100,
      height: 100)
      imageLogo.center.x -= 400
         self.view.addSubview(imageLogo)

 //animate labelLogo
    self.labelLogo.frame =
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21)
    self.labelLogo.center.x -= 400
    self.labelLogo.text = "Your booking is confirmed!"
    self.labelLogo.textAlignment = .center
        self.view.addSubview(labelLogo)
 }//end of animateDidLayout






 //animate the logo when the view has appeared
  //call it in ViewDidAppear

   func animateDidAppear() {
       guard let appeared = self.logoAppeared, appeared == false else{
         print("appeared is true in viewDidAppear, in else")
           return
 }

     print("appeared value in viewDidAppear  after else \(appeared)")

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.1, options: [],
                   animations: {

     //animate overlayView
    // self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    //self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    //self.overlayView.alpha = 0.4


  //animate labelLogo
   self.labelLogo.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 100,    
    y: 340, width: 200, height: 21)

   self.labelLogo.text = "Your booking is confirmed!"
   self.labelLogo.textColor = .white
   self.labelLogo.textAlignment = .center
   self.labelLogo.sizeToFit()

    //animate imageLogo
     self.imageLogo.frame =
     CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 50,y: 250,width: 100,height: 90)

       }) { finished in

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,    
  selector: #selector(ThirteenthViewController.startCounting), userInfo: nil,      
    repeats: true)  
     }
} //end of animateDidAppear
```

[image: overlayView not hidden]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either use a delay or use another animation with a delay to remove hide the views. I would not rely on the timer.  Example with animation to remove using your code and removing the timer.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var counter = 0
let paymentLogo = UIImage(named: "paymentImage")
var imageLogo:UIImageView!
var overlayView = UIView()
var logoAppeared:Bool? = false
let labelLogo = UILabel()


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    //move picture off screen
    animateDidLayout()
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //move picture on screen and adjust view
    animateDidAppear()
}



//animate the image before it appears on screen
func animateDidLayout(){
    guard let appeared = self.logoAppeared, appeared == false else{
        print("appeared is true in viewDidLayoutSubviews, in else")
        return
    }

    print("appeared value after else in ViewDidLayoutSubvies \(appeared)")

    //animate overlayView
    if self.view.subviews.contains(overlayView) != true{
        self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(self.overlayView)
    }

    self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.overlayView.layer.opacity = 0.4
    self.overlayView.alpha = 0.4



    //animate imageLogo
    if self.view.subviews.contains(imageLogo) != true{
        self.imageLogo = UIImageView(image:paymentLogo)
        self.view.addSubview(imageLogo)
    }

    imageLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100,
                             height: 100)
    imageLogo.center.x -= 400


    //animate labelLogo
    self.labelLogo.frame =
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21)
    self.labelLogo.center.x -= 400
    self.labelLogo.text = "Your booking is confirmed!"
    self.labelLogo.textAlignment = .center
    if self.view.subviews.contains(labelLogo) != true{
        self.view.addSubview(labelLogo)
    }

}//end of animateDidLayout







//animate the logo when the view has appeared
//call it in ViewDidAppear

func animateDidAppear() {
    guard let appeared = self.logoAppeared, appeared == false else{
        print("appeared is true in viewDidAppear, in else")
        return
    }

    print("appeared value in viewDidAppear  after else \(appeared)")

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.1, options: [],
                   animations: {

                    //animate overlayView
                    // self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
                    //self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                    //self.overlayView.alpha = 0.4


                    //animate labelLogo
                    self.labelLogo.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 100,
                                                  y: 340, width: 200, height: 21)

                    self.labelLogo.text = "Your booking is confirmed!"
                    self.labelLogo.textColor = .white
                    self.labelLogo.textAlignment = .center
                    self.labelLogo.sizeToFit()

                    //animate imageLogo
                    self.imageLogo.frame =
                        CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 50,y: 250,width: 100,height: 90)

    }) { finished in

    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 5.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.overlayView.alpha = 0
        self.imageLogo.alpha = 0
        self.labelLogo.alpha = 0

    }, completion: {
        finished in
        self.overlayView.isHidden = true //it is hidden :)
        self.imageLogo.isHidden = true
        self.labelLogo.isHidden = true
        self.logoAppeared = true
    })

} //end of animateDidAppear}
```

If you prefer to wait 5 seconds and hide without animation you could use

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {// Your code with delay}
```

Or as a really fun alternative using your code and the delay

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var counter = 0
let paymentLogo = UIImage(named: "paymentImage")
var imageLogo:UIImageView!
var overlayView = UIView()
var logoAppeared:Bool? = false
let labelLogo = UILabel()


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    //move picture off screen
    animateDidLayout()
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //move picture on screen and adjust view
    animateDidAppear()
}



//animate the image before it appears on screen
func animateDidLayout(){
    guard let appeared = self.logoAppeared, appeared == false else{
        print("appeared is true in viewDidLayoutSubviews, in else")
        return
    }

    print("appeared value after else in ViewDidLayoutSubvies \(appeared)")

    //animate overlayView
    if self.view.subviews.contains(overlayView) != true{
        self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(self.overlayView)
    }

    self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.overlayView.layer.opacity = 0.4
    self.overlayView.alpha = 0.4



    //animate imageLogo
    if self.view.subviews.contains(imageLogo) != true{
        self.imageLogo = UIImageView(image:paymentLogo)
        self.view.addSubview(imageLogo)
    }

    imageLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100,
                             height: 100)
    imageLogo.center.x -= 400


    //animate labelLogo
    self.labelLogo.frame =
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21)
    self.labelLogo.center.x -= 400
    self.labelLogo.text = "Your booking is confirmed!"
    self.labelLogo.textAlignment = .center
    if self.view.subviews.contains(labelLogo) != true{
        self.view.addSubview(labelLogo)
    }

}//end of animateDidLayout







//animate the logo when the view has appeared
//call it in ViewDidAppear

func animateDidAppear() {
    guard let appeared = self.logoAppeared, appeared == false else{
        print("appeared is true in viewDidAppear, in else")
        return
    }

    print("appeared value in viewDidAppear  after else \(appeared)")

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.1, options: [],
                   animations: {

                    //animate overlayView
                    // self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
                    //self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                    //self.overlayView.alpha = 0.4


                    //animate labelLogo
                    self.labelLogo.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 100,
                                                  y: 340, width: 200, height: 21)

                    self.labelLogo.text = "Your booking is confirmed!"
                    self.labelLogo.textColor = .white
                    self.labelLogo.textAlignment = .center
                    self.labelLogo.sizeToFit()

                    //animate imageLogo
                    self.imageLogo.frame =
                        CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 50,y: 250,width: 100,height: 90)

    }) { finished in

    }

     let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.type = "suckEffect"
        self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        self.overlayView.isHidden = true //it is hidden :)
        self.imageLogo.isHidden = true
        self.labelLogo.isHidden = true
        self.logoAppeared = true
    }

} //end of animateDidAppear}
```

Comment: I tried both versions. `overlayView` is not hidden,it's still on screen and can't interact with the button because basically it's on top of it. Please see image http://imgur.com/a/niY9y . Did you test your code in Xcode? Many thanks

Comment: It absolutely works and yes I used Xcode.  Do you have other methods I don't know about?  Is this controller presented modally or something?  Did you add the lines of code to animateDidAppear and remove the timer? Would you like to see a video which tells me there is something else going on that I am not aware of?

Comment: Edited Answer as I think you have this presented modally.

Comment: This controller is instantiated as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458405 . I am uploading the video now and will post it here in 15 mins.

Comment: Have you tried the new code.  I think the overlay view is hidden it is your view controller  that is still over top of the other view controller.  Can you tell me do you have an opacity set on the view controller and is it over current context or fullscreen?    New controller should dismiss with the edited code I provided above

Comment: I have tried the new code  and I get same result. Here is the video that I made prior to trying your new code. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lWqbMgvNjg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: So a couple of things.  I edited to pop the navigation controller.  Why are you instantiating a new navigation controller before pushing.  Also why not present modally.  Either way the code above will pop the navigation controller and provided the old controller is in the stack it would be there.This is not an animation issue it is a view stack issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136770/discussion-between-agibson007-and-bibscy).

Comment: Please update your answer with this statement you showed me so as to avoid setting the overlayView twice. `if self.view.subviews.contains(overlayView) != true{ }` . I think others will find it interesting that viewDidLayoutSubviews() is actually called twice.