# Performing Segue from Another Class via a Function Without Storyboards

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to perform a segue from another class via a class function.

I have a class called `MyTableViewController`. In that class I have constructed a view controller of the type `AnswerViewController`. A segue to this view controller is supposed to occur when a condition in the `Extension : MyCell` is met. The problem that I am having is that the function `showNextView` is not being called.

I have read posts on both [Perform Segue From Another Swift File via a class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285517/perform-segue-from-another-swift-file-via-a-class-function) and [Perform Segue from another class with helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458405/perform-segue-from-another-class-with-helper-function), but both of these create a segue *before* constructing the view controller (which I cannot do because I am not using storyboards and do not actually have segues, only `pushViewController`).

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//Construct View Controller
let answerViewController = AnswerViewController()

//Create goToNextView function which will be called in extension MyCell
func goToNextView(){
    navigationController?.pushViewController(answerViewController, animated: true)
}
}



extension MyCell: YSSegmentedControlDelegate{
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {


    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index
    print(tagToIndex)

 //Condition To Be Met
 if tagToIndex == [0:1,1:0,2:1]{

 //Access function goToNextView from MyTableViewController

   func showNextView(fromViewController : MyTableViewController){
        fromViewController.goToNextView()
    }
}

}        
}
```

How do I call the `showNextView` function so that the segue occurs?

Thanks, 
Nick

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this that way. Your `showNextView` function is nested inside `segmentedControl(_, willPressItemAt)` - this means it is not accessible outside of it. You generally shouldn't use nested functions.

To solve your issue you should create a delegate for your cell and inform your view controller that an action has occured.

A simple example :

```
protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
    func myCellRequestedToOpenAnswerVC(cell: MyCell)
}

class MyCell {
    weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    // rest of your inplementation
}
```

Then, change `segmentedControl(_, willPressItemAt)` to :

```
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {


    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index
    print(tagToIndex)

 //Condition To Be Met
 if tagToIndex == [0:1,1:0,2:1]{

     self.delegate?.myCellRequestedToOpenAnswerVC(cell: self)
}

}
```

The last part happens in `MyTableViewController` - first, in your `cellForRow` method assign the view controller as delegate, something like this - `cell.delegate = self`, and make the view controller conform to `MyCellDelegate`:

```
extension MyTableViewController: MyCellDelegate {

    func myCellRequestedToOpenAnswerVC(cell: MyCell) {
        self.goToNextView()
    }
}
```

Now, whenever the condition is met, your view controller will get informed about it and be able to act accordingly.

If you are not familiar with protocols and delegation pattern, I highly recommend [reading through the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html), as it is something used extensively in CocoaTouch.